# Flyway - set permissions and password for an Oracle schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, flyway

I'm configuring an Oracle VM taken from [here](https://github.com/hilverd/vagrant-ubuntu-oracle-xe) and want to tweak the default schema generated there as an example of the Flyway integration.

The Flyway is used there to create a new Oracle schema called `MYSCHEMA`. So the Flyway user is `system` (default Oracle dba) and the password is system's password, that is:

```
    <flyway.user>system</flyway.user>
    <flyway.password>manager</flyway.password>
    <flyway.schemas>MYSCHEMA</flyway.schemas>
```

Now I have two tasks:

1. I need to set a specific password for `MYSCHEMA` or at least to know what password has the Flyway set for it.
2. I need to set specific user permissions (`GRANT`s) for the `MYSCHEMA` user.

Both tasks should be executed by `system` user. Besides, there is no point to run them on every migration. Once is enough.

Can I do it inside the Flyway using callbacks or migrations?

**Update:** default password seem to be "flyway", but the `MYSCHEMA` lacks CREATE SESSION privilege.

Comment: Update. I'm using beforeMigrate.sql callback for the moment — it is executed by "system" and therefore GRANTs permissions successfully. It is a little bit overhead, but solves the problem.